# Cup product: binary internal or external operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Having a look at the definition of cup product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_product
I harbour some doubts as to whether it is a binary internal operation (or function) or rather an external one. I am inclined to say it is an internal one but would like your support on that (if possible with a simple explanation)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two. One external $H^*(X)\otimes H^*(Y)\to H^*(X\times Y)$ (which is sometimes called the cross product), and an internal one $H^*(X)\otimes H^*(Y)\to H^*(X)$ (which is obtained from the former taking $Y=X$ and composing with the map induced by the diagonal inclusion $X\to X\times X$.

Comment: The book by Dold has a (slightly extenuating) description of all this.

Comment: I am thinking of the binary operation exclusively, not of the higher order ones.....

Comment: Neither I did nor Dold does ever mention anything "higher".

Comment: Are you conflicted because in $\smile : H^p(X) \otimes H^q(X) \to H^{p+q}(X)$, the indices are different? In this sense it is "external" (it's not a binary law on a single set), but if you look at $H^*(X) = \bigoplus_{p \ge 0} H^p(X)$ it becomes "internal". That difference does not really matter much, anyway.